# Leaderboard position SQL optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm offering an experience leaderboard for a Discord bot I actively develop with stuff like profile cards showing one's rank. The SQL query I'm currently using works flawlessly, however I notice that this query takes a rather long processing time.

```sql
    SELECT id, 
           discord_id, 
           discord_tag, 
           xp, 
           level 
    FROM   (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS id, 
                   discord_id, 
                   discord_tag, 
                   xp, 
                   level 
            FROM   profile_xp, 
                   (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
            ORDER  BY xp DESC) t 
    WHERE  discord_id = '12345678901';
```

The table isn't too big (roughly 20k unique records), but this query is taking anywhere between 300-450ms on average, which piles up relatively fast with a lot of concurrent requests.

I was wondering if this query can be optimized to increase performance. I've isolated this to this query, the rest of the MySQL server is responsive and swift.

I'd be happy about any hint and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: I think you can achieve same output without having it as inner query.

Comment: I don't quite understand what reason there could be to calculate an old-style row_number. While those are unique records. Is it for paging the results? And why the WHERE criteria in the outer query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're scanning 20,000 rows to assign "row numbers" then selecting exactly one row from it. You can use aggregation instead:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM profile_xp AS x
    WHERE xp > profile_xp.xp
) + 1 AS rnk
FROM profile_xp
WHERE discord_id = '12345678901'
```

This will give you *rank* of the player. For *dense rank* use `COUNT(DISTINCT xp)`. Create an index on `xp` column if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) This query drastically reduced the latency down to 10-15ms on average!

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer; too long for a comment:

I usually write this kind of thing exactly the same way that you have done, because it's quick and easy, but actually there's a technical flaw with this method - although it only becomes apparent in certain situations.

By way of illustration, consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ints;

CREATE TABLE ints (i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO ints VALUES
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Your query:

```
 SELECT a.*
      , @i:=@i+1 rank
   FROM ints a
   JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
  ORDER
     BY RAND() DESC;
    +---+------+
    | i | rank |
    +---+------+
    | 3 |    4 |
    | 2 |    3 |
    | 5 |    6 |
    | 1 |    2 |
    | 7 |    8 |
    | 9 |   10 |
    | 4 |    5 |
    | 6 |    7 |
    | 8 |    9 |
    | 0 |    1 |
    +---+------+
```

Look, the result set isn't 'random' at all. `rank` always corresponds to `i`

Now compare that with the following:

```
SELECT a.*
     , @i:=@i+1 rank 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * FROM ints ORDER by RAND() DESC) a 
  JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars;
+---+------+
| i | rank |
+---+------+
| 5 |    1 |
| 2 |    2 |
| 8 |    3 |
| 7 |    4 |
| 4 |    5 |
| 6 |    6 |
| 0 |    7 |
| 1 |    8 |
| 3 |    9 |
| 9 |   10 |
+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming discord_id is the primary key for the table, and you're just trying to get one entry's "rank", you should be able to take a different approach.

```
SELECT px.discord_id, px.discord_tag, px.xp, px.level
   , 1 + COUNT(leaders.xp) AS rank
   , 1 + COUNT(DISTINCT leaders.xp) AS altRank
FROM profile_xp AS px
LEFT JOIN profile_xp AS leaders ON px.xp < leaders.xp
WHERE px.discord_id = '12345678901'
GROUP BY px.discord_id, px.discord_tag, px.xp, px.level
;
```

Note I have "rank" and "altRank". `rank` should give you a similar position to what you were originally looking for; your results could have fluctuated for "ties", this `rank` will always put tied players at their highest "tie". If 3 records tie for 2nd place, those (queried separately with this) will show 2nd place, the next xp down would should 5th place (assuming 1 in 1st, 2,3,4 in 2nd, 5 in 5th). The `altRank` would "close the gaps" putting 5 in the 3rd place "group".

I would also recommend an index on `xp` to speed this up further.